# Google.Cloud.AppEngine.V1 client libraries and traffic splitting in .NET

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use the Client Libraries provided by Google to move traffic from one version of an app in AppEngine to another. However, the documentation for doing this just talks about using the rest API and not the client libraries.

Here is some example code:

```
var servicesClient = Google.Cloud.AppEngine.V1.ServicesClient.Create();
var updateServiceRequest = new UpdateServiceRequest();
updateServiceRequest.Name = "apps/myProject/services/myService";
var updateMask = new Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.FieldMask();
updateServiceRequest.UpdateMask = updateMask;

// See below for what should go here...

var updateResponse = servicesClient.UpdateService(updateServiceRequest);
```

My question is what format do I use for the update mask?
According to the documentation I should put in:
`split {"split": { "allocations": { "newVersion": 1 } } }`
But when I try: `updateMask.Paths.Add(@"split { ""split"": { ""allocations"": { ""myNewVersion"": 1 } } }");`

... I get the exception:

`"This operation is only supported on the following field(s): [labels, migration_config, network_settings, split, tag_to_target_map], but got field(s): [split { "split": { "allocations": { "myNewVersion": 1 } } }] from the update request.`

Any ideas where I should put the details of the split in the field mask object? The property Paths just seems to be a collection of strings.

The examples for these libraries in Google's doco is pretty poor :-(

Comment: Could you please share the documentation  that you followed ? I want to take a look

Comment: Hi Andie - this is the page I was following: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/migrating-splitting-traffic but trying to use the .NET client libraries and an UpdateServiceRequest: https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AppEngine.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AppEngine.V1.UpdateServiceRequest

Comment: Verifying the documentation that you shared, I noticed that the API patch has the following format ….. {"split": { "shardBy": "IP", "allocations": { "v2": "1" } } }, now, the format that you are setting is   “....split {    "split": { "allocations": {  "newVersion": 1 } } } “  the split is duplicated, did you try only setting one?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. :-(

Comment: It seems that it will be better to raise a bug in [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet) in order that the team verifies this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I raised a support ticket with Google and despite them suggesting a solution which didn't work exactly (due to trying to assign a string to the UpdateMask which needs a FieldMask object), I managed to use it to find the correct solution.

The code should be:

```
// appService is a previously retrieved Service object from the ListServices method
var updateServiceRequest = new UpdateServiceRequest();
updateServiceRequest.Name = appService.Name;
updateServiceRequest.UpdateMask = new Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.FieldMask();
updateServiceRequest.UpdateMask.Paths.Add("split");
appService.Split.Allocations.Clear();
appService.Split.Allocations["newServiceVerison"] = 1;
updateServiceRequest.Service = appService;
```